# Как создать кастомное отображение контроллера для всех окон?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

Как задать параметры UINavigationController следующего типа для всех существующих окон ?

(Пример настройки отображения для каждого окна ниже)

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"85af02"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar
 setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для создания глобального стиля UI элементов в приложении используется `UIAppearance`.
Если проперти в хедере объявлена с макросом `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`, то ее стиль можно установить один раз для всех объектов с помощью протокола `UIAppearance`.
Например, в `UINavigationBar.h`:

```
@property(nullable, nonatomic,strong) UIColor *barTintColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
@property(nullable,nonatomic,copy) NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *titleTextAttributes NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
@property(nonatomic,assign,getter=isTranslucent) BOOL translucent NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

Для этих пропертей можно использовать UIAppearance:

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[UINavigationBar appearance].titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:21]};
[UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = YES;
```

Если для отдельных частей приложения нужно установить разный стиль, можно использовать `appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:`.

Проперти `tintColor` в `UINavigationBar` объявлена без `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`, то есть для нее нужно какое-то другое решение.
Например, поскольку это `navigationBar`, то можно установить его `tintColor` один раз при создании `navigationController`:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Тогда все `navigationBar` внутри этого `navigationController` будут иметь заданный `tintColor`. Если у вас несколько `navigationController`, то это надо будет сделать для каждого отдельно.

Comment: Спасибо вам за полноценный ответ !